# In a callable Firebase Cloud Function, how do i discern which code to use when i throw an error?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

When catching an error in a **Firebase Cloud Function**, the [Firebase documentation for handling errors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors) does not explain clearly which error code is appropriate to set for failed reads/writes to Firestore.

Given the following function:

```
exports.myCustomFunction = functions.https.onCall( async (data, context) => {
  
  if (!context.auth) {
    // Throwing this error is self explanatory and works as expected.
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unauthenticated", "User must be authenticated.");
  }

  const uid = context.auth.uid;
  const userQuery = admin.firestore().collection("users").where("userId", "==", uid);

  try {
   const user = await userQuery.limit(1).get();
   // do stuff...

  } catch (error) {
    // ******* THIS IS THE ERROR I NEED HELP WITH *******
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("aborted", "user_query", {error: error});
  }

});
```

If a Firestore query, as i have set in the above function, fails, or for that matter, if *any* Firestore read/write, or a Firestore batch set, fails for any reason, what would be the appropriate error code to set?

The options seem limited. Should it be `aborted` or `unknown`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error codes that you can pass to the [HttpsError](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/common_providers_https.httpserror) constructor are listed in the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/common_providers_https#functionserrorcode).  If you encounter an error that your code can't resolve now or in the foreseeable future, usually you use "internal", which translates to the usual 500 HTTP status code. This lets the client know that something went wrong that was the fault of the backend and can't necessarily be fixed by a simple retry.

Comment: Thanks. With respect to the response data that is received client side, i have found that if i exclude the `details` param then i receive the `message`, but if both are set, i only receive the `details`. In both scenarios, Firebase also prefixes the response with the string 'FirebaseError: ' so i am having to parse the error just to get the actual response. Do we have any control over this? Is it possible to receive both the message and details?

Comment: I think you should ask a second question that illustrates focuses on your specific observations of what isn't working the way you expect along with the enough code, both client and backend, that allows someone to reproduce what you see.  (On Stack Overflow, there is a limit of one question per post - I was only able to answer you first question.)

Comment: Understood, ill update and remove the second question.